# ARM Cortex-A8 L2 cache miss overhead

Tags: arm, cpu, pipeline, cpu-cache, cortex-a

I am reading ARM Cortex-A8 data sheet, in data sheet ARM stated that an Load data that missed in L2 take at least 28 core cycle to complete, now i could not imagine that during this 28 cycle CPU will stall and put bubble in pipeline or execute other instruction until this load complete? what if we have an branch based on this load result? what if we have another load just after that instruction that again missed in L2??

Comment: This is the reason for caches.  28 seems small if you are running with dram, but the quote says "at least".    Depends heavily on your system of course.  And of course it will (eventually) stall the pipe if instruction or data is required for the processor to move forward is held up by these cache misses.

Comment: Very possible to have one, two, many misses in a row in L1/L2 that cause dozens of clocks for each.  And can get even worse if there are only dirty lines in the cache available and you have to wait for the write back to dram to happen before the read can happen.  You can also get lucky and have one operation cause an eviction only to have the result of that operation need the thing that was just evicted.  This is just how computers work now, the processor does not by itself determine performance.

Comment: dram is not within arms domain in general so arm can only document their portion.  the chip vendor chooses dram tech and IP and the board vendor chooses the dram parts and somewhere in there someone picks the speeds within the choices for that dram.  These choices are added to the arm documented numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even under a cache miss, the pipeline will go on until the RAW (read after write) dependency bites.

```
ldr     r12, [r0], #4
subs    r12, r12, r1
beq     end_loop
```

The `subs` instruction cannot be executed at the same time as `ldr` due to the RAW dependency.
The `beq` instruction cannot be executed at the same time as `subs` due to the CPSR RAW dependency.

All in all, the sequence above will take 6 cycles in best case: three cycles instruction execution plus 3 cycles L1 hit latency while it will be 3 + 28 = 31 cycles in worst case (total cache miss)

Comment: Thanks, i have another question. Cortex-a8 is an in order processor, how this behavior can change if Cortex-a8 was an out of order processor? Also i think that in your example branch prediction unit will predict flow of programe after branch and execute some instructions speculatively, if during this speculative execution we have another L2 chache miss and then cpu find that it had wrong speculation, it will cancel second L2 cache miss and did not load second data in cache??

Comment: @alirezasadeghpour The size of the `rob` (reorder buffer) and the loop size matter on the out-of-order core. If the `rob` is big enough for the given loop, there will be no latencies at all, and all the execution pipelines will be filled, resulting in maximum performance. If the loop contains too many instructions, if the instruction sequence has too many dependencies, etc, there will be latencies here and there. You can't tell for certain, there are simply too many factors that might affect the performance. Just keep the loop size and dependencies at bay, and hope for the best.

Comment: @alirezasadeghpour Keep in mind that out-of-order cores are at least three times as large and pricy, and consume as much more power than in-order ones, and thus, there will always in-order versions of new architectures either for `big.LITTLE` configuration or even stand-alone ones. Always do your best for the in-order version, and consider the out-of-order benefits a bonus performance boost.